# Run .sh file in one line command

Tags: 16.04, command-line, sh

How to start `sh` file in one line command ?
This is how I normally start `sh` file in the specific path

```
user@user:~$ cd idea-IC-171.4424.56/bin
user@user:~/idea-IC-171.4424.56/bin$ ./idea.sh
```

If I would like to start the command in one line like below, I will get error

```
user@user:~/idea-IC-171.4424.56/bin$ cd idea-IC-171.4424.56/bin/idea.sh
bash: cd: idea-IC-171.4424.56/bin/idea.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Use a ";" to separate your commands

Comment: Honestly depends on your commands and what you are expecting to see.  See:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100704/difference-between-executing-multiple-commands-with-and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a ";" to seperate your commands

```
cd idea-IC-171.4424.56/bin ; ./idea.sh
```

*You could use `./idea-IC-171.4424.56/bin/idea.sh` to run it, however the results may be different as if the [shell] script accesses files in the current or relative directory, it won't find them as you didn't `cd` there before run.*